# Java SimpleHTTPServer equivalent to "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"

Tags: java, http, groovy

Is there a simple java/jvm/groovy server that could be used to serve files simply like 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer ' http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: I'm looking for something that is a part of the JVM, Groovy.  Something that I can @Grab or a jar that I can drop in

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/groovy-one-liner-to-run-HttpServer-td3245538.html

$ groovy -l 80 SimpleWebServer

Comment: the SimpleWebServer script is in the examples

Answer (score 0):

There is [JEP 408](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/408) in development to implement exactly that. Just using standard `java` command you will be able to start simple http server:

```sh
$ java -m jdk.httpserver [-b bind address] [-p port] [-d directory] \
  [-o none|info|verbose] [-h to show help message]
```

Unfortunately it won't be released until Java 18+ most likely. So in the mean time you would have to look for other solutions like [this one](https://www.jbang.dev/learn/jep-408-with-jbang/) for example or cook your own
thing.